# Printing the last run through a recursive function? Python

Tags: python, recursion

My program needs an to have an option to display each step of the recursion function or not to display and just display the results. How would I implement this ? Would I use a counter of some sort in the function? Whenever I would put the print function in the base case it was just displaying the first run .

Comment: Okay just added the recursive function.

Answer (score 3):

You can save metadata to the function itself.  Or if you want something more complicated, you could use a class and the **call** method.  An example of adding metadata to a function:

```
def my_func(x):
    my_func.last_value
    return x ** 2
a = my_func(5)
print my_func._last_value
5
```